# Can weak convergence be checked on an orthonormal basis?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthnormal basis $(e_i)_{i\in I}$.
Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $H$ with $\langle x_n, e_i\rangle \to \langle x, e_i\rangle$ for some $x\in H$ and all $i\in I$. Can we conclude from this that that $(x_n)_{n}$ converges weakly?

My intuition says no but I didn't find a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, if you know that your sequence (or net) is **bounded**. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883236/weak-net-convergence-in-ell-p-where-1-p-infty/1883383#1883383) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239862/boundedness-and-pointwise-convergence-imply-weak-convergence-in-ellp) for more general results. For unbounded nets you may still have pointwise convergence to 0, without being weakly convergent, so in general [the answer is **no**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1884259/17929).

Comment: Wow, your answer provides everything I could wish for. Thanks alot!