# Question about convergence of nets in $X^*$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space with dual $X^*.$ Let ${a_i}$ and ${b_i}$ be two nets in $X^*$ such that $a_i$ is norm-bounded in $X^*$ and $a_i \to a$ and $a_i + b_i \to 0$,  where in both the convergence is understood in terms of weak-star Topology.

My question is that from above can we conclude that the $(b_i)$ is norm-bounded or at least admits a bounded subnet ? 
What if $X$ be reflexive ?

Comment: You can slightly modify my example from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/158933/822.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Not even if $a_i=0$ for all $i$.

If $b_i$ converges weak* to $0$ it does not follow that $b_i$ is bounded.  It does not follow that $b_i$ has a bounded subnet.  The thing to observe: every weak* neighborhood of $0$ is an unbounded set.  Using that we can build a net $b_i$ that converges weak* to $0$ but $\|b_i\|$ converges to $\infty$.

Try it yourself!

Comment: HOWEVER.  A sequence $b_i$ that converges weak* is, indeed, bounded.

Comment: In the sequence case if put $b_n = n e_n \in \ell^2 $  I think is counter example again! Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes, $n e_n$ does not converge weak*.  Indeed, $(1,2^{-3/4},3^{-3/4},\cdots) \in l^2$, right?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks, is there any well-known result that confirms that?

Comment: Uniform Boundedness Principle + "a convergent sequence of scalars is bounded".