# Is $C$ weakly closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

following question jumped into my mind.

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $C$ be a nonempty subset of $X$. Set

$$A : =  \{ x \in X \;|\; \exists \text{ a norm-bounded net } x_{i} \to x \text{ (weakly) } \, \forall i: x_i \in C \}$$

Question 1 : Is $A$ actually the entire weak-closure of C?

Question 2 : Is $A$ weakly closed set?

I'm positive that the answer of 1 is NO, but dont have explicit example. This is because in any infinite dimension space one can construct a net $x_i$ such that $\| x_i \| \to \infty$ but $x_i \to 0~(weakly)$.

Question 2 is harder, I tried to prove it, I had to go through some diagonal process regarding for index sets, which was kinda impossible !! Now I changed my mind, and start to find a counter example instead of proving it.

Any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @copper.hat no, nets are weird see the answer here
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3262680/219176

Comment: I realised that after I posted my comments. I avoid nets except for fishing and accounting.

Comment: Note that $C\subseteq A\subseteq\overline{C}$ and so 1 and 2 are equivalent, right?

Comment: @freakish Thanks right. good observation

Comment: @copper.hat   I start to understand  them, so I start keep asking  questions here from experts. Now I feel like I asked too many dumb questions about them, that's embarrassing

Comment: @Redshoes see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825790/every-weak-convergent-sequence-is-bounded I knew there was something odd with your question. The link you've posted is about weak-* convergence, not weak convergence. Is that a typo in your question?

Comment: @freakish  No .   if that works in any infinite dimension then it also works for weak convergence as  well. Just take reflexive spaces, then weak-star is actually weak topology

Comment: @Redshoes Yeah, you're right. Anyway the proof in the link I've posted is for sequences only. But I'm not sure why it doesn't generalize to nets...

Comment: Also the problem is that even if $(b_i)$ is a net without a bounded subnet then we still can create a bounded net from elements $\{b_i\}$ convergent to some point outside of $\{b_i\}$. Being a subnet is a stronger condition (cofinality). Note that this cannot be done with sequences. Yet another anomaly with nets. And a major problem in finding a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both questions is negative. Here are some counterexamples in $\ell^2$.

For
$$C := \{ e_n + n \, e_m \mathrel\mid n,m \in \mathbb N,\; n < m \}$$
one hase
$$A = C \cup \{ e_n \mathrel\mid n \in \mathbb N \}$$
but the weak closure of $C$ contains $0$. The set $A$ is also not weakly closed.

For another example, you can take
$$ C:= \{ \sqrt{n} \, e_n \mathrel\mid n \in \mathbb N\}.$$
Then, $A = C$, but again, the weak closure of $C$ contains $0$.

Conclusion: nets are weird.

Comment: How do you show that the weak closure in both cases contains $0$?

Comment: Thanks.  we always have $C \subseteq A$, so your first example need to be modified. right?

Comment: Yes. I had only written down the limit points which are not in $C$. I will edit my answer.