# A characterization for closed sets in topological vector spaces

Tags: weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces, nets

> If $X$ is a topological vector space(specially  a Banach space with it's weak topology), Does $X$ have the following
>   property:
>
> A subset  $A$ is closed $\Leftrightarrow $ every
>   **bounded** net in $A$ converent to an $x_0$, implies $x_0\in A$.

In Metric spaces, this is true, because every converging net in a metric space has a bounded subnet(even has an eventually bounded subnet). But in a topological vector space, a net (according to [Must a weakly or weak-* convergent net be eventually bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158902/must-a-weakly-or-weak-convergent-net-be-eventually-bounded)) may be doesn't have an eventually bounded subnet(although I don't know about a bounded subnet).

Can anyone help or guide me? I think this is a hard problem.

Comment: To be clear, you are asking about a characterization of closed sets in the *weak topology* on the dual space $X^*$, correct?

Comment: Closed sets in $(X,\tau_w)$.

Comment: Although in every T.V.S, I don't know the answer

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the definition of weak topology. It indeed is a topology on $X$, not the dual space $X^*$. Please disregard my prior comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general a topological vector space doesn't have that property.

#### An example in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ in its weak topology:

For $m \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, let
$$A_m = \bigl\{ x \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) : \lVert x\rVert_2 = m, \bigl(n \leqslant \tfrac{m(m-1)}{2} \lor n > \tfrac{m(m+1)}{2}\bigr) \implies x_n = 0\bigr\}$$
and define
$$A = \bigcup_{m = 1}^{\infty} A_m\,.$$
Then the intersection of $A$ with every closed and bounded set is compact (even in the strong topology), thus all accumulation points of bounded nets in $A$ lie in $A$, in particular if a bounded net in $A$ converges to $x_0$, then $x_0 \in A$.

But $A$ is not weakly closed, we have $0 \in \operatorname{cl}_w(A) \setminus A$. For every weak neighbourhood of $0$ contains one of the form
$$V(\varepsilon;\xi_1, \dotsc, \xi_k) = \{ x \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) : \lvert\langle x, \xi_j\rangle\rvert < \varepsilon \text{ for } 1 \leqslant j \leqslant k\} $$
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\xi_1,\dotsc,\xi_k \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, and $\varepsilon > 0$. And $V(\varepsilon;\xi_1,\dotsc,\xi_k) \cap A_m \neq \varnothing$ for all $m > k$.

This construction can be imitated in every infinite-dimensional normed space and yields a set that isn't weakly closed but whose intersection with every weakly closed bounded set is weakly closed.

The property holds (as you know) in every metrisable topological vector space.

For **convex** $A$ we have the equivalence
$$A\text{ closed} \iff (A\cap B)\text{ closed for all closed and bounded } B$$
if $X$ carries the weak topology of an originally locally convex and metrisable space. In particular in the weak topology of a Banach space, closed *convex* sets can be characterised by the convergence of bounded nets.