# Can I find a sequence converging weakly to a weak limit point?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space and $E^*$ its dual. If $A$ is a subset of $E$ and $x$ is a weak limit point of $A$, i.e. every weakly open deleted neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$, can we always find a sequence $x_n\in A$ that converges weakly to $x$?

This property is enjoyed by any metric spaces, as we can determine how large a neighborhood is using the metric. But the weak topology is known to be not metrizable, and the answer to this question becomes less evident.

Is there a proof or a counterexample?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454992/a-characterization-for-closed-sets-in-topological-vector-spaces) is a counterexample.