# How to show that a weak-star convergent sequence is norm bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

In this MSE [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158902/must-a-weakly-or-weak-convergent-net-be-eventually-bounded), the author stated that

> as a consequence of uniform boundedness principle, a weak-star convergent *sequence* is norm bounded.

I tried to prove it but to no avail.
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It says: uniform boundedness principle.  Why not begin by  writing down the UBP?

Comment: As GEdgar says: write down the statement of the Uniform Bounded Principle and the result is obvious.  Typical the UBP talks about a family of operators $T_n$ -- compare with the $x^*_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Claim}$: Let X be a banach space and $K^* \subset X^*$ a weak-star compact set. Then $K^*$ is norm bounded.

$\textbf{Proof}$: Let
$$e \colon X \to X^{**}, \  \ x \mapsto e(x) \in X^*,  \text { with }  \langle e(x),x^* \rangle = \langle x^*,x \rangle, \ \text{ for any } x^* \in X^* $$ be the canonical isometric embedding.

For every $ x \in X $, the functional  $ e(x) \colon X^* \to \mathbb R $ is (by definition)  $ w^*-$continuous and therefore the set  $ e(x) (K^*) \subset \mathbb R $ is compact. Hence,  $  \sup_{x^* \in K^*}  | \langle e_x ,x^* \rangle | < \infty
   $ and so,   $    \sup_{x^* \in K^*} | \langle x^*,x \rangle|< \infty$.
In other words, the family of operators   $  \{ x^* \}_{x^* \in K^*} $ is pointwise bounded (for every  $ x \in X $)  and since  $ X $ is  Banach, applying the uniform boundedness principle,  we have that
$  \sup_{x^* \in K^*} ||x^*|| < \infty$.

Now, if $(x^*_n)_n \subset X^*$ is a weak-star convergent sequence with limit $x^*$, then the set $\{ x^*_n,x^*\}_n$ is weak-star compact.