# Question about weak and strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following exercise that concerns me:

Let $X$ be a normed space and $X^*$ its dual space. Suppose $\text{s-lim}\ l_n = l$ and $x_n \to x$. Then $l_n(x_n) \to l(x)$. Does this still hold, if $\text{s-lim}\ l_n = l$ and $x_n \rightharpoonup x$?

We use the following definitions for strong and weak convergence: if $l(x_n) \to l(x)$, we say that $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ and we write $x_n \rightharpoonup x$. Furthermore, we have $\text{s-lim} \ l_n = l$ iff $l_n(x) \to l(x)$.

My answer to the first question: we look at

$$\lVert l_n(x_n) - l(x) \rVert \leq \lVert l_n(x_n) - l(x_n)\rVert + \lVert l(x_n) - l(x)\Vert \leq \lVert l_n(x_n) - l(x_n)\rVert + \lVert l \rVert \lVert x_n - x \rVert \to 0$$

where we have used the strong convergence $\text{s-lim}\ l_n = l$ for the first and the norm convergence $x_n \to x$ for the second summand.

Now, based on my approach and the definitions I have given, the second question also has to be true. But I am a little bit unsure about that and I think someone really has to pay attention to the details when it comes to dealing with weak and strong convergence. Could anyone maybe help me with that?

Comment: $l_n(x) \to l(x)$ for all $x$ does not give you $l_n(x_n) \to l(x_n)$. You cannot make $x$ dependent on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimate you need is similar to what you did. You have
\begin{align}
|l_n(x_n)-l(x)|
&\leq |l_n(x_n)-l_n(x)|+|l_n(x)-l(x)|\\[0.2cm]
&\leq\|l_n\|\,\|x_n-x\|+|l_n(x)-l(x)|.
\end{align}
Now, because a [weak$^*$-convergent sequence is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790208/how-to-show-that-a-weak-star-convergent-sequence-is-norm-bounded), there exists $c>0$ with $\|l_n\|\leq c$. This gives us
\begin{align}
|l_n(x_n)-l(x)|
&\leq c\,\|x_n-x\|+|l_n(x)-l(x)|.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\limsup_n|l_n(x_n)-l(x)|
&\leq \limsup_n c\,\|x-x_n\|+|l(x_n)-l(x)|=0.
\end{align}
This proves that the limit exists and $\lim_n|l_n(x_n)-l(x)|=0$.

When $x_n\rightharpoonup  x$, the result can fail. For instance let $X=c_0$, and consider the canonical basis $e_n$. Then $e_n\rightharpoonup 0$. Consider also $e_n\in \ell^1=c_0^*$. This gives us the functionals $l_n(x)=x_n$. Given any $x\in c_0$,
$$
l_n(x)=x_n\to0, 
$$
so $l_n\to0$ in the weak$^*$-topology. But $l_n(e_n)=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I think the expression $$l_n(x_n)-l(x)=l_n(x_n-x)+l_n(x)-l(x)$$ gives the convergence faster, with no need to introduce $x_m.$

Comment: Yes indeed! $ \ $

Comment: Moreover a slightly simpler example is provided by any orthonormal sequence $e_n$ in a Hilbert space. It  tends to $0$ weakly by the Bessel inequality and $\langle e_n,e_n\rangle=1.$ Sorry for being pain ...

Comment: No worries. But it's the same example, isn't it. Just in $\ell^2$-$\ell^2$ instead of $c_0$-$\ell^1$.

Comment: The same, except that the underlying spaces are different. I always consider inner product spaces simpler than the normed ones.