# Unital $*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$ is weakly closed if its closed unit ball is weakly closed

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A$ be a $*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$ and $\mathbf 1\in A.$ Let $U$ denotes the closed unit ball of $A$. Given that $U$ is weakly closed. Then I want to show that $A$ is weakly closed.
I know that, weak topology and ultraweak topology coincides on unit ball and then I stuck here and do not know how to proceed. Please help me to solve this. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the fact that a weakly convergent net is norm bounded and thus its limit lies in a closed ball of $A$?

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos A weakly convergent *sequence* is norm bounded, but a weakly convergent net is not necessarily so. See *e.g.* [Nate Eldredge's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158902/must-a-weakly-or-weak-convergent-net-be-eventually-bounded)

Comment: @DenOfZero Do you know the Krein-Smulian theorem or the Banach-Dieudonné theorem? A linear subspace $E$ of a dual Banach space $V^*$ is weak-* closed iff the intersection $E \cap \mathrm{Ball}(V^*)$ is weak-* closed. Are you trying to prove the Kaplansky density theorem?

Comment: @RobertFurber Sorry, I didn't know the Krein-Smulian theorem. If I follow this theorem then, $U$ is weakly closed implies $U$ is weak-$*$ closed, as ultra weak topology and weak-$*$ topology both coincides on $B(H)$. So from the theorem, $A$ is weak-$*$ closed. But I have two questions, first is how can I assume $A$ as $V^*$, that is dual of a Banach space and also from the theorem we have $A$ is weak-$*$ closed but I want to show $A$ is weakly closed.

Comment: @DenOfZero For Krein-Smulian you don't need that $A$ is $V^*$, only that $B(H)$ is (and it's the dual of the trace-class operators). To get from weak-\* closed to weakly closed, use the fact that a weak-\*-closed set is ultrastrongly closed, and an ultrastrongly closed *-algebra is equal to its bicommutant, and therefore weakly closed by the bicommutant theorem. (You have to use the \*-algebra structure somehow because there are weak-\*-closed hyperplanes that are not weakly closed.)

Comment: But maybe, if you are not trying to reprove it, what you want is the Kaplansky density theorem.